# MongoDb pymongo how to increment multiple documents

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a document as following in MongoDb

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("53490030cf3b942d63cfbc7b"),
   "dt" : ISODate("2014-04-12T00:00:00Z"),
   "uId" : "abdc123", "count" : 12 
 }
```

I have a list of uIds as `["abdc123","abc","cde","efg"]`

I need to increment  count by one for  each uId matching todays date .if any uId has no value in todays "dt" then update should add a new doc  for each UIDS with  count 1

My query in python follows

```
client.Mydb.mycoll.update(
    {
       "uId":{"$in":["abdc123","abc","cde","efg"]},
       "dt":datetime(y,m,d)
    },
    {"$inc":{"count":1}},
    upsert=True,
    multi=True
)
```

but output is not as expected,it create only one document with count 1

suggest me the correct query in  pymongo

Update:for incrementing an  already existing value the above code works,but no new document is creating if "uId" and "dt" not in collection

Comment: If this is actually inserting a document then it is not matching any document. So this seems to point to your `datetime()` function not producing the result you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For doing the record update as mentioned you need to work with pymongo.bulk.BulkUpsertOperation as following

```
from pymongo.bulk import BulkUpsertOperation
bulk=clientConn.db.table.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

for i in someList:
    bulk.find({'uid':i,"dt":datetime(y,m,d)}).upsert().update({'$inc': {'count': 1}})
res=bulk.execute()
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Why did you import `BulkUpsertOperation` if it's not used?

Comment: Yes, why did you import BulkUpsertOperation? How can we use it to .upsert() on the bulk object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do something like below to make it work..

```
["abdc123","abc","cde","efg"] { ///lopp all of them
  client.Mydb.mycoll.update({
    "uId": <loop-variable>, // for each value .. eg. "abc123" ... 
    "dt":datetime(y,m,d)},{"$inc":{"count":1}
    },
    upsert=True,
    multi=True
   )
}
```